# Is it possible to track something else with a counter_cache other than the number of objects in an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, counter-cache

All I am trying to do, is in an easy/light way...whenever the `PostsController#Show` action is fired, to increment the `post.views` or `post.view_count` column. I don't want to have to do anything too heavy.

It feels like the native `counter_cache` would be perfect...but that is specifically for association object count.

Anyway I can re-purpose that? Or use the underlying concepts in the way I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use counter cache directly, but you can use the underlying increment function.  [See the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods/increment_counter).  To do what you say, you'd want:

```
Post.increment_counter(:view_count, post.id)
```

This issues a single SQL `update` command.

Comment: So I would just put this in the `show` action, un a successful render, correct?

Comment: @marcamillion Probably. It's impossible to say without seeing your code.